# How to customise a chart in Pinescript?

Tags: charts, pine-script

I'm trying to create my own chart. Interested in customized trading hours on the chart.

Found a similar code. But it does not work correctly. The problem is that it cuts out the beginning and end of all data. And I need to cut the beginning and the end of every day.

```
study("Candle cutter", overlay=false)

bar_num = nz(bar_num[1]) + 1
threshold = input(1, "candle # start")

_open = (bar_num > threshold) ? open : na
_high = (bar_num > threshold) ? high : na
_low = (bar_num > threshold) ? low : na
_close = (bar_num > threshold) ? close : na

plotcandle(_open, _high, _low, _close, title='Title', color = _open < _close ? green : red, wickcolor=black)
```

Tell me, how is it possible to change? How to solve the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "it cuts out the beginning and end of all data" ?

Comment: Sorry for my English. I mean. The functionality need to cut specify hours. For example - the sesion is from 12am to 12pm. I need to cut 4 hours from the chart from 1am to 4am. And the script on the example just only cut specify bars on all the chart. No every day

Comment: I'm also having a hard time understanding what do you mean by "cut". Why 4 hours from 1am to 4am if session is 12am to 12pm ? What are you trying to see in the end ?

Comment: As an example of how it works, we can take extended trading time in stocks. Each terminal has the option to disable extended trading hours. What I exectly mean you can see on that video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WUJHQc-Lha0

Comment: Something the same realized in Ninja Trader https://ninjatrader.com/support/helpGuides/nt8/en-us/?using_the_trading_hours_window.htm Tab "How to create and edit a Trading Hour Template"